# Where is the image captured from iOS?

Tags: swift, camera, photo

When using the default camera in swift, I use this to take the picture and then show it in an imageView:

```
@IBAction func takePhoto() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But I want to take the image that I just took and store that image in a constant, but I don't know what is the image I took. I have tried using this as the image

```
UIImage(named: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)
```

`UIImage(named: "spect a string here")` and `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` returns me a string so that is why I thought that could be the image, but it seems that it won't work.

Comment: Why not store `imageView.image` in a variable after setting the imageView?

Comment: How? I two images one that is from my computer (the default image shown in the image view) and the other image is the one you can take with the camera

Comment: I'm confused. Is the imageView displaying the image that you just took with the camera already or is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: The imageView displays an image by default when you haven't taken any photos yet lets call it "photoA", but then when you take a photo "photoB" the imageView changes the displayed image from photoA to photoB, and I am adding filters to the image so I want to know where I can take the image so I can display the original image without being affected by a filter

Comment: How about this: save the image to a variable from the imageView, and *then* add the filters.

Comment: But what's would be the name of the image or the reference to the image I just took?

Comment: Okay, I see. Take a look at http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/take-photo-tutorial-ios8-swift. It's *really* short. The image that you took *is* `imageView.image`. That is your constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99067/discussion-between-pixele9-and-dopapp).

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? If so, could you please accept it? If not, please, tell me and I'll add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say something like:

```
var photo = UIImage() // Accessible from anywhere in the class
@IBAction func takePhoto() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage // Assign `photo` to the image
}
```

In the above code, `photo` is a variable accessible from anywhere in the class. Therefore, it is accessible from all of your functions and handlers. `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage` is the image from the camera, and in the code, you're changing the variable `photo` to the image from the camera. Now, the image from the camera is available later from anywhere in that class.